simplicial commutative rings and derived commutative rings
I met two definitions with regard to the simplicial(or derived) commutative rings. One way is very direct and literal, that is, a 'simplicial ring' is a simplicial object in the category of ring：
\begin{equation}
A_{sim}\in Fun(\triangle^{op},CRing)
\end{equation}
which can be understood as a ring equipped with a simplicial set structure.
While I also see another definition of 'derived commutative rings':
\begin{equation}
A_{anim}\in Fun_{\prod}(Poly_{\mathbf{Z}}^{op},Grpd_{\infty})
\end{equation} which is the animation of the algebraic category $CRing\cong Fun_{\prod}(Poly_{\mathbf{Z}}^{op},Set)$ (Here $Fun_{\prod}$ denotes functors preserving finite products).
The underling space of $A_{anim}\in Fun_{\prod}(Poly_{\mathbf{Z}}^{op},Grpd_{\infty})$ corresponds to an infinite groupoid, that is, $A_{anim}(Z[T])$, and information about algebraic operation is encoded in the Hom between polynomial rings. In this way, we give the infinite groupoid $A_{anim}(Z[T])$ a 'ring' structure. However, this ring structure is not 'strict' in that its equational theory is 'coherent up to homotopy', like its associativity laws. But for a simplicial ring $A_{sim}$: it consists of a collection of commutative rings $\{A_{i}\}_{i\in N}$ with face maps and degeneracy maps between them, every $A_{i}$ is a 'strict' ring with strict associativity.
Sometimes they are both called the 'simplicial commutative rings'. But one is a ring equipped with an infinite category structure while another is an infinite category equipped with a 'ring' structure. So I can't help asking:
$\textbf{Question}$: Is this 'ring' $A_{anim}(Z[T])$ an object in $Fun(\triangle^{op},CRing)$? Does this 'coherent up to homotopy' ring $A_{anim}(Z[T])$ corresponds to some simplicial ring $A_{sim}$?
I see that there are ways of presenting a model category into an infinite category, see Daniël Apol's answer, and I also hear that the infinite localization of the category of simplicial rings $Fun(\triangle^{op},CRing)$ is equivalent to the infinite category $Fun(Poly_{\mathbf{Z}}^{op},CRing)$, these are all about the equivalence between collections of things as a whole (like category or infinite category), but what's going on with a single object, like a certain simplicial ring or derived commutative ring, what is their relationship?

It is true that a simplicial ring $A_\mathrm{sim}\in\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{CRing})\simeq\mathrm{Fun}_\Pi(\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{sSet})$ ''is'' a derived commutative ring $\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty$ in a very direct way: passing from a simplicial set to the underlying $\infty$-groupoid (i.e. passing to the underlying homotopy type), $A_\mathrm{sim}$ encodes also a ''strict'' commutative ring structure on the homotopy type underlying the simplicial set underlying $A_\mathrm{sim}$ (although in my head, there are no strict equalities when dealing with homotopy types, but hopefully you understand what I meant with ''strict'' here) and hence also a commutative ring structure up to coherent homotopy. Let us write $|A_\mathrm{sim}|$ for this underlying derived ring.
This also makes it clear why the reverse direction is more subtle: given a derived commutative ring $A_\mathrm{anim}\in\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty)$, the homotopy type $A_\mathrm{anim}(\mathbb{Z}[T])$ cannot even unambiguously be considered a simplicial set: for every homotopy type, there may be many simplicial sets of that homotopy type. Moreover, the commutative ring structure on $A_\mathrm{anim}$ is only given up to coherent homotopy, while a strict simplicial ring wants to have a strict commutative ring structure. This means that $A_\mathrm{anim}(\mathbb{Z}[T])$ cannot be considered an object in $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{CRing})$ in a very direct way.
We could still ask if it corresponds to some strict simplicial ring in a more complicated way.This means we have to somehow (a) find a simplicial set to represent the homotopy type $A_\mathrm{anim}(\mathbb{Z}[T])$ and (b) find a strict ring structure on this simplicial set that is up to homotopy the same as the homotopy-coherent ring structure on $A_\mathrm{anim}(\mathbb{Z}[T])$. In short, we want to find a simplicial ring $A'_\mathrm{sim}$ such that $|A'_\mathrm{sim}|\simeq A_\mathrm{anim}$ as derived rings. It is a priori not clear that this is possible. However, it is a consequence of the fact that $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty)$ is the underlying $\infty$-category of the model category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{sSet})$ (and part of the proof of this fact) that for every derived commutative ring $A_\mathrm{anim}$, you can indeed find such a strict simplicial ring $A'_\mathrm{sim}$. In practice, however, it can be very difficult to actually know what this simplicial ring looks like. In some cases, you can make an educated guess, and in others, you can perform some model categorical computations to figure it out, but in general it is hardly possible.
A similar statement holds for maps of derived rings: any map $f_\mathrm{anim}\colon A_\mathrm{anim}\to B_\mathrm{anim}$ of derived rings can be ''strictified'' (which is the term often used for this process, as is ''rigidification'') to a map $f'_\mathrm{sim}\colon A'_\mathrm{sim}\to B'_\mathrm{sim}$ of strict simplicial rings, that satisfies $|f'_\mathrm{sim}|\simeq f_\mathrm{anim}$ (leaving equivalences $|A'_\mathrm{sim}|\simeq A_\mathrm{anim}$ and $|B'_\mathrm{sim}|\simeq B_\mathrm{anim}$ implicit). Once more, it might be possible to guess what $f'_\mathrm{sim}$ is in special cases, but in general you just know that it exists, as it is practically impossible to figure out what it actually looks like (and even if you can figure out, there is the question if it is actually an enlightening/useful description that you end up with).
Now, why do people give the same name to the strict and homotopy-coherent versions? In short: we actually only care about simplicial/derived rings up to homotopy anyway. In this sense, you can get away with both ways of looking at them, because up to some homotopies they are the same notion. This is also what this equivalence of $\infty$-categories tells you: it means that the homotopy theories of strict simplicial rings and derived rings are the same. However, working in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Fun}_\Pi(\mathrm{Poly}_\mathbb{Z}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty)$ has theoretical advantages as working in $\infty$-categories is often a lot less painful than working in model categories, while working in $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{CRing})$ has the advantage that you can actually construct and check things ''on points/combinatorially'' if you would want to. I personally see the second as a technical tool to aid the study of the first, which is for me the natural setting in which to talk about (the homotopy theory of) simplicial rings.

Thank you so much for your answer, it's very great!  Are there any references for the fact that $Fun(Poly^{op}, Grpd_{\infty})$ is the underlying infinite category of $Fun(Poly^{op},sSet)$?

This is essentially Theorem 6.4 in Badzioch's Algebraic Theories in Homotopy Theory. He establishes a Quillen equivalence between model categories, and one of those consists of functors $\mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{sSet}$ that preserve products up to weak equivalence, so it suffices to see that this model category has $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty)$ as underlying $\infty$-category. This rolls out from Lurie's Prop. 4.2.4.4 in Higher Topos Theory, which shows that the model category of all functors $\mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{sSet}$ has(...)

(...) $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{Grpd}\infty)$ as underlying $\infty$-category. Since we are interested in a full subcategory, it suffices to show that a functor $F\colon \mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{sSet}$ that preserves products up to weak equivalence induces a functor $F\colon\mathrm{Poly}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Grpd}\infty$ that preserves products (up to equivalence in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Grpd}_\infty$). This follows from(...)

(...) the fact that 1) products  in $\mathrm{sSet}$ become products in $\mathrm{Grpd}\infty$, and 2) weak equivalences in $\mathrm{sSet}$ become weak equivalences in $\mathrm{Grpd}\infty$.
